# TYPO3: Automatic wrapping CASE by page.layout

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I'm having a big teaser image at the top of the page. The author may select in the backend whether the teaser image should be static or a animated slideshow. I'm using bootstrap for the slideshow btw.

The selection appears at Page > Edit > Appearance
Rootpage TSConfig:

```
TCEFORM.pages {
    layout.altLabels.1 = Default (with Slideshow)
    layout.altLabels.0 = Default
}
```

Now, it gets a bit trickier.
To get the Bootstrap slider running, you need to have an outer wrap and each slide wrapped, too. This is what I've got so far:

```
page.10.variables {
    teaser < styles.content.get
    teaser.select.where = colPos = 0
    teaser.stdWrap.required = 1
    teaser.stdWrap.wrap {
        cObject = CASE 
        cObject {
            key.field = layout

            default = TEXT
            default.value = |

            1 = TEXT
            1.value = <div id="teaser" ...>|</div> ### shortened 
        }
    }

    teaser.renderObj.stdWrap.wrap {
        cObject = CASE 
        cObject {
            key.field = layout

            default = TEXT
            default.value = |

            1 = TEXT
            1.value = <div class="item">|</div>
        }
    }
}
```

The first `teaser.stdWrap.wrap` works like a charm. Selecting the Frontend Layout wraps the teaser correspondingly.
But the `teaser.renderObj.stdWrap.wrap` doesn't want to work. Mainly, because I think that the key of the `CASE` is not the Frontend Layout, but the layout of the content element. **How to change that?**

Second question. This is how the wraps currently look like (or how they would look if the TS above would work as intended):

```
<div class="item">
    <div id="c14">
        <div class="ce-textpic ce-right ce-intext">
            <div class="ce-gallery" data-ce-columns="1" data-ce-images="1">
                <div class="ce-row">
                    <div class="ce-column">
                        <div class="ce-media">
                            <img src="img.jpg" width="1150" height="632" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="ce-bodytext"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Is there a way to make it look more or less like this?**

```
<div class="item">
    <img class="slide" src="img.jpg">
</div>
```

The customer doesn't wish to have any captions or text, so it can be ignored.

I'm running TYPO3 7.6.6 with fluid_styled_content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer for the 1st question:

You can use the "getText" data type in TypoScript. See in doc [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Gettext/Index.html#page).

It has a predefined variable for the current page record. So simple change the second key attribute so:

```
key.data = page:layout
```

But if you are running the system with fluid_styled_content, then you can simply use fluid to solve this problem. (There you can access the layout with `data.layout` )

To answer the second question:

Yes. It is possible, you need to take a look into the fluid_styled_content extension. There you find a lot about the templates, layouts and the elements. You can simply override them with your templates and you can get rid of any not wanted `div` inside.

To do so, I can recommend you a german [video](https://jweiland.net/video-anleitungen/typo3/typo3-projekte-verwalten/fluid-styled-content-templates-anpassen.html).

Comment: What a coincidence - I'm German ;) The video helped a lot. I just added a fluid-condition to wrap things differently when the FE layout is different. Thank you very much!